# How to fire query from the result of another query in php

Tags: php, android, mysql

So basically, i have a furniture type, furniture color, furniture size, furniture cost and furniture material. now i have combo box showing various possible values to choose. In all combo boxex, i have also entered a value named "all" incase the user dont want to filter in that particular way.
now i want to search the furniture on the basis of input from user.

but due to the value named "all", i am facing lots of problems.
so i need to fire query from the result of the previous query, so that i can keep conditions in the php file and if value is other than "all" then the query should execute.

Please help me..

Search_Furniture.java file

```
public class Search_Furniture extends Activity 
{   
 Spinner type,color,cost,size,material;
 String atype, acolor, acost, asize, amaterial;
 Button search;
 List<String> l2;
 JsonParser jsonparser = new JsonParser();
 ProgressDialog pDialog;
 private static final String loginUrl = "http://realroom.byethost24.com/realroom/search.php";

 private static final String success = "success";    
 private static final String message = "message";
 ArrayAdapter<String> adp2;
 int pos;
 SessionManager session;

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_furniture);

        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        type = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.fur_type);
        cost = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.price);
        color = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.fur_color);
        size = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.fur_size);
        search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
        material = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.fur_mat);            

        type.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pos=arg2;
                add();
            }
            private void add() 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch(pos)
                {
                    case 0:
                        l2= new ArrayList<String>();   
                        l2.add("All");
                        adp2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Search_Furniture.this,R.layout.spinner_item ,l2);
                        adp2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
                        size.setAdapter(adp2);
                    break;
                    case 1:
                        l2= new ArrayList<String>();  
                        l2.add("All");
                        l2.add("2-Sit");
                        l2.add("3-Sit");
                        l2.add("L-Shape");
                        l2.add("Sofa+Chair");
                        adp2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Search_Furniture.this,R.layout.spinner_item ,l2);
                        adp2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
                        size.setAdapter(adp2);
    //                  select();
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        l2= new ArrayList<String>();      
                        l2.add("All");
                        l2.add("2*2");
                        l2.add("3*3");
                        l2.add("4*4");
                        adp2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Search_Furniture.this,R.layout.spinner_item,l2);
                        adp2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
                        size.setAdapter(adp2);
        //              select();
                    break;
                    case 3:
                        l2= new ArrayList<String>();    
                        l2.add("All");
                        adp2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Search_Furniture.this,R.layout.spinner_item,l2);
                        adp2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
                        size.setAdapter(adp2);
        //              select();
                    break;
                    case 4:
                        l2= new ArrayList<String>();   
                        l2.add("All");
                        l2.add("Jumbo");
                        l2.add("King Size");
                        l2.add("Double Bed");
                        l2.add("Single Bed");
                        adp2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Search_Furniture.this,R.layout.spinner_item,l2);
                        adp2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
                        size.setAdapter(adp2);
            //          select();
                    break;
                    case 5:
                        l2= new ArrayList<String>();
                        l2.add("All");
                        l2.add("Single");
                        l2.add("Double");
                        adp2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Search_Furniture.this,R.layout.spinner_item,l2);
                        adp2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
                        size.setAdapter(adp2);
            //          select();
                    break;
                    case 6:
                        l2= new ArrayList<String>();  
                        l2.add("All");
                        l2.add("4-Sitter");
                        l2.add("6-Sitter");
                        l2.add("8-Sitter");
                        l2.add("10-Sitter");
                        adp2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Search_Furniture.this,R.layout.spinner_item,l2);
                        adp2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
                        size.setAdapter(adp2);
            //          select();
                    break;
                }
            }   


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });


        search.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new Search().execute();
    //          Intent i = new Intent(Search_Furniture.this,Items.class);
    //          startActivity(i);    
            }
        });  



 }

 /* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)
 */
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater blowup = getMenuInflater();
        blowup.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i;
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.checkout:
                i = new Intent(Search_Furniture.this, MyCart.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            case R.id.aboutUs:
               i = new Intent(Search_Furniture.this,AboutUs.class);
               startActivity(i);
               break;

            case R.id.profile:
               i = new Intent(Search_Furniture.this,Profile.class);
               startActivity(i);
               break;

            case R.id.help:
               i = new Intent(Search_Furniture.this,Help.class);
               startActivity(i);
               break;

            case R.id.logout:
                session.logoutUser();
                   break;

        }
        return false;
    }

class Search extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
 {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog=new ProgressDialog(Search_Furniture.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Customizing your Furniture");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            String atype = type.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String acost = cost.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String acolor = color.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String asize = size.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String amaterial = material.getSelectedItem().toString();

            try {
                List<NameValuePair> para = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                para.add(new BasicNameValuePair("f_type", atype));
                para.add(new BasicNameValuePair("f_cost", acost));
                para.add(new BasicNameValuePair("f_color", acolor));
                para.add(new BasicNameValuePair("f_size", asize));
                para.add(new BasicNameValuePair("f_material", amaterial));

                System.out.println(atype);
                System.out.println(acost);
                System.out.println(acolor);
                System.out.println(asize);
                System.out.println(amaterial);
                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                JSONObject json = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest(loginUrl, "POST", para);
                Log.d("Create response", json.toString());
                int res = json.getInt(success);
                if (res == 1) 
                {
                    Intent i =new Intent(Search_Furniture.this, Furniture.class);
                    startActivity(i);
      //              Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                    finish();
                    return json.getString(message);
                } 
            } 
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url)
        {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

How  to write the php query in mysql for the above facility..??

Or is there any other way by which i can provide this facility in my app..??

Comment: Add the second request in the `onPostExecute` method depending on the results received

Comment: your question is not clear, mention what exactly do you want, instead of 'the above facility'

Comment: But how can i fire the query in php from the result.?

Comment: @yazan, i want to execute a query2 to the result that i get after executing the query1

Comment: Instead of executing query to the particular table i want to execute on the resultant table of query 1